# $\frac{SU(2)}{N}= U(1) \times Z_2$. Find $N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, exact-sequence

Consider the short exact sequence

$$
1 \to N \to SU(2) \to U(1) \times Z_2 \to 1
$$

What is the normal subgroup $N$ here so that $U(1) \times Z_2$ is a quotient group and $SU(2)/N= U(1) \times Z_2$? Is it an allowed short exact sequence?

The $U(1)= R/Z$ as an Abelian compact complex phase, and $Z_2$ is $Z/2Z$ as
a finite group of order 2.

Any comment welcome, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an allowed short exact sequence of *topological* groups.  $SU(2) \to U(1) \times \Bbb Z_2$ must be *onto*, which means that it cannot also be *continuous* since $SU(2)$ is connected whereas $U(1) \times \Bbb Z_2$ is not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment +1, let me wait for other answers.

Comment: No problem. Are you interested in a potentially discontinuous group homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, could you illuminate this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047197?