# $\frac{SU(2)}{N}= Q$. Examples of finite groups $N$ and $Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let us consider
$$
1 \to N \to SU(2) \to Q  \to 1
$$

> **(1). Can we find some examples of $N$ and $Q$ so that either $N$ or $Q$ contain finite groups?**

We know $SU(2)/Z_2=SO(3)$, so we can choose $N=Z_2$ and $Q=SO(3)$ as an example. Here $Z_n$ is $Z/nZ$ as a finite group of order $n$.

Since $SU(2)$ contains the quaternion $H_8$ as a subgroup (correct?), then $SU(2) \supset H_8$. We know $H_8/Z_2=(Z_2)^2$ and $H_8/Z_4=Z_2$. Do we have something similar by replacing $H_8$ by $SU(2)$? Does it make sense to consider:

> (2)
>   $$SU(2)/N=(Z_2)^2$$
>   $$SU(2)/Z_2=SO(3) \text{  ( see the above )}$$
>   $$SU(2)/N=Z_2$$
>   $$SU(2)/Z_4=Q$$
>   **What are these $N$ and $Q$ if they make senses?**

-

> **(3) If $H_8$ is a normal subgroup** of $SU(2)$ (is this true?), then we can ask 
>   $$
> 1 \to H_8 \to SU(2) \to Q  \to 1
> $$
>   **What is $Q=SU(2)/H_8=?$**

Partial answers are welcome!

Comment: Partial answer: $SU(2)$ has no nontrivial finite *normal* subgroups.  Notably, if $N$ contains a non-zero element $h$, then it must contain the entirety of the orbit
$$
\{ghg^{-1} : g \in SU(2)\}
$$
which is necessarily infinite.

Comment: And, as I mentioned in my [other answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047142/fracsu2n-u1-times-z-2-find-n/2047159?noredirect=1#comment4202263_2047159): if $Q$ is finite (and non-trivial), then $SU(2) \to Q$ cannot be a continuous homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, so you rule out (3), $SU(2)$ does not have $H_8$ as normal subgroups. I am glad to meet an expert here. :)

Comment: I've made a mistake!  $SU(2)$ has a non-trivial center.  So, its center $\{I, -I\}$ is a normal subgroup.  I think that the argument does apply, however, to any subgroup besides this one.

Comment: By "$SU(2) \to Q$ cannot be a continuous homomorphism, if Q is finite (and non-trivial)" --- do you mean that $Q$ cannot be a non-identity finite group as a quotient group of $SU(2)$? Why is that? Intuitively you seem right, but what is the more rigorous argument? (no need to prove, I am an engineer.)

Comment: again, continuous maps necessarily take connected sets to connected set.  A finite (or for that matter, countable) set with more than one element is not connected.

Comment: I am curious as to what an engineer would be doing with exact sequences, though

Comment: (1) Does $SU(2)/Z_4=Q$ make sense? Should $Z_4$ be a normal subgroup of $SU(2)$??? (2) Then your $Z_2$ center example, I had $SU(2)/Z_2=SO(3)$ as I already mention.

Comment: If there's any chance for that to make sense, $Z_4$ would have to be a normal subgroup of $SU(2)$.  For the quotient $G/H$ to make sense, $H$ needs to be normal in $G$.  I don't think we can find a normal $Z_4$ in $SU(2)$ for reasons already stated.  In particular, there are infinitely many matrices in $SU(2)$ whose eigenvalues are $\pm i$, and all of them are conjugate to any candidate generator of $Z_4$ within $SU(2)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thank you very much, it seems to me that you are claiming that my questions (2) and (3) are impossible, thus negative attempt--- except the only example I gave: $SU(2)/Z_2=SO(3)$? Perhaps my question (1) is also negative?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, and miss-tery, how about this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047269/?

Comment: @miss-tery in fact, it seems that $SO(3)$ is a simple group, so there are no other possibilities for a normal $N \subset SU(2) \cong SO(3) \times Z_2$

Comment: Thanks. Why do you use isomorphic for $SU(2) \cong SO(3) \times Z_2$? is that true??? I know $SU(2)/Z_2 \cong SO(3)$ instead.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, $SU(2)$ is isomorphic to **unit quaternions** but SU(2) is NOT isomorphic to **quaternions H_8**? See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185472/how-to-show-su2-mathbbz-2-cong-so3/185492#185492

Comment: @miss-tery ooof, you're right.  I meant $SU(2)/Z_2 \cong SO(3)$. In any case, that's still enough to deduce that because $SO(3)$ is simple, there are no more normal subgroups.