# Can $\frac{SO(5)}{N}= SU(2) \times SO(2)$ be true?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, exact-sequence

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047197/), consider the unknown short exact sequence,

$$
1 \to N \to SO(5) \to SU(2) \times SO(2)   \to 1
$$

What is the normal subgroup $N$ here so that $SU(2) \times U(1)$ is a quotient group for the total group $SO(50$, and $SO(5)/N= SU(2) \times SO(2)$? Is it an allowed short exact sequence? (Here $SO(2)$ is the same as a $S^1$ circle and a $U(1)$.)

Comment: $SO(5)$ is a simple Lie group; it has no nontrivial quotients whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you, the expert! How about $O(5)$, $O(4)$ and $SO(4)$? This is practical for elementary particle physics.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is the same true for $SO(n)$ for odd $n$ in general?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, how can we determine whether O(n) or SO(n) are simple or not? I think O(n) has a chance to fulfill this exact sequence???